# Worklight Direct Update, Google Play

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

With todays announcement
http://www.zdnet.com/google-outlaws-android-app-updates-that-dont-come-from-its-play-store-7000014574/

What does that mean for Worklights direct update functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's policy just brings them inline with Apple's policy and only applies when you need to change the native code associated with your application. Direct updates from Worklight, which are just updating the cached HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc. resources, would not be impacted as they are not updating the native application code.

Comment: Hi, can you give a reference url to your answer or is it just what you think?

Comment: From the article: "An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism" ... Worklight Direct Updates do not change the APK binary code, only the cached resources. This is described in the InfoCenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_direct_updates_app_versions_to_mob.html